# How to run rmf_simulation using docker

Tags: ros

I am trying to run `rmf_simulation`, `rmf` API and dashboard using docker containers as per [the documentation](https://github.com/open-rmf/rmf_deployment_template#alternate-method-for-quick-local-deployment)

Below are the commands used:-

```bash
for rmf_simulation
docker run --network=host \
-it ghcr.io/open-rmf/rmf_deployment_template/rmf-simulation:latest \
bash -c "ros2 launch rmf_demos_gz office.launch.xml \
headless:=1 \
server_uri:=ws://localhost:8000/_internal"


for rmf_api_server
docker run --network=host \
-it ghcr.io/open-rmf/rmf_deployment_template/rmf-web-rmf-server:latest


for rmf_dashboard
docker run -p 3000:80 \
-it ghcr.io/open-rmf/rmf_deployment_template/rmf-web-dashboard-local:latest
```

According to the docs, rmf_simulation and rmf_api images should run on network host of docker(--network=host), and for the rmf_dashboard, the port must be exposed.
But on frontend, i am getting the below error.[image: the below error]

The frontend is not able to communicate with the backend.

Is this because the rmf_simulation and rmf_api containers are running in --network=host and the rmf_dashboard(the frontend) is not,
or is it a rmf problem.
How do i make the rmf_simulation, rmf_api and rmf_dashboard containers run together seamlessly?

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! I suggest adding more information, such as the version of OS, ROS, etc. Furthermore, you may share the commands with the output shown in your terminal. At present, it looks like an issue with your docker, and I can't guess further with the limited information!

Comment: Thanks, I have made the changes